# How I code an upload/download code using Angular/TypeScript with JSON?

Tags: html, json, angular, forms, typescript

I want to send to my json api, a file, and how I bind this field of HTML, to the property of my component.ts (ex.: 'conteudo.file', or 'file') and send to my api.

I try this way:

//IN component.ts file

```
conteudo: Conteudo[];
editConteudo: Conteudo;

constructor(private contService: ConteudoService) {}

add(conteudo: Conteudo){
    this.contService.addConteudo(this.editConteudo).subscribe();
    console.log('Os dados enviados foram: ', conteudo);
}
```

//IN service.ts

```
private url: string = 'http://localhost:8000/conteudo';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addConteudo(conteudo: Conteudo): Observable<Conteudo>{
      return this.http.post<Conteudo>(this.url, conteudo)
  }
```

//IN component.html file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="add(conteudo)" class="was-validated">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="validationTextarea">Título</label>
            <textarea class="form-control is-invalid" [(ngModel)]="titulo" 
                  name="titulo" placeholder="Required example textarea" 
                  required>
           </textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter a message in the textarea.
            </div>
       </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
   </form>
```

//In conteudo.ts file

```
export interface Conteudo {
     id: number;
     titulo: string;
     descricao: string;
     file: string;
 }
```

//In a db.json file

```
{
  "conteudo": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "titulo": "Teste de Controle de Dados",
      "descricao": "Testando controle de arquivos",

      //Here, where I want to pass my file.
      "file": "example.pdf, example.jpg, etc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can base64 encode the file to send it in JSON though the size of this will be quite large! Alternatively and in my opinion the better approach, you can send it as form data.

```
addConteudo(conteudo: Conteudo): Observable<Conteudo>{
      let formData = new FormData;
      formData.append("file", conteudo.file)
      return this.http.post<Conteudo>(this.url, formData )
  }
```

You can get access to the file in the following way.

```
  <input type="file" name="test" (change)="getFile($event)"/>
```

```
getFile(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
}
```

Comment: So, the "problem" that I have is: How I get the content of the fields in html?

(ex.: 
<form (ngSubmit)="add(conteudo)">

      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="titulo" name="titulo"/>
      <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="myFile" name="myFile"/>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

Comment: Ah okay sorry i didn't fully understand your problem.

I would suggest the following and move away from ngModel for this. I have modified my ansert to show this. Hope it helps!